# Rotate camera with mouse buttons without reseting?

Tags: c++, opengl, camera, glfw, glm-math

I wanted to make the camera rotate using mouse buttons.

The camera rotates very well, but the problem is with mouse buttons. When I release the mouse button and press it again, the rotation resets back to center(0.0, 0.0f, 0.0f):

```cpp
void mouse_input(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int action, int mods)
{
    if (key == GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_MIDDLE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        mousemovement = true;
        glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED);
    }
    if (key == GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_MIDDLE && action == GLFW_RELEASE)
    {
        mousemovement = false;
        glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_NORMAL);
    }
}
void cursor_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos)
{
    float lastposx = 1920.0f / 2;
    float lastposy = 1080.0f / 2;
    if (mousemovement)
    {
        if (firstMouse) {
            lastposx = xpos;
            lastposy = ypos;
            firstMouse = false;
        }
        float speed = 0.05f;
        float offsetx= 0.0f;
        float offsety = 0.0f;
        offsetx = (xpos - direction.x);
        offsety = (direction.y - ypos);
        float jaw = 0.0f;
        float pitch = -90.0f;
        offsetx *= speed;
        offsety *= speed;
        jaw += offsetx;
        pitch += offsety;
        if (pitch < -90.0f)
        {
            pitch = -90.0f;
        }
        if (90.0f < pitch)
        {
            pitch = 90.0f;
        }
        direction.x = cos(glm::radians(jaw)) * cos(glm::radians(pitch));
        direction.y = sin(glm::radians(pitch));
        direction.z = sin(glm::radians(jaw)) * cos(glm::radians(pitch));
        cameraFront = glm::normalize(direction);
        lastposx = xpos;
        lastposy = ypos;
    }
    else
    {
        previouscamerafront = direction;

    }
}
```

I tried to make another vec3 variable with the prevouis camera Front.

I expected to have a rotating camera using middle mouse button.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Too much irrelevant code. Show only the part, which is related to the rotation. You have to describe your problem better, currently it is not clear (at least to me) what your code does and what it is supposed to do.

Comment: If it helps, with a button press/release, you'll have two points. Those two points can be used to describe a 2-dimensional motion vector. With that vector, you have the information about the movement in the x and y direction, which can be used to calculate the rotation around the corresponding axes. That can be done either by accumulating the rotation values (increase the rotation values by the specific amounts) or respond directly to them (the amounts represent the rotation values). But it is not quite clear which one you prefer (and if it is that kind of rotation you have in mind).

Comment: As an addendum, by pressing a modifier key or using the middle mouse button, you could restrict the rotation to the z-axis or swap any of the x- or y-axis with the z-axis. Which coordinate you use, is up to you but it makes more sense to use the y-offset as the rotation value.

Comment: yea sorry, that I didnt described my problems better I just dont know how to describe the problem better. I just edited the irrelevant code, that only shows wich is related to the rotation, I hope its better. And I gonna try to explain better: "I want to make a camera moves around and look around when holding mouse middle button. camera moves very well and look around too, but the only problem is that, when I hold mouse middle button and release and hold again it will reset to the position where I started(center) back when I started to hold." I hope I explained better :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[GLFW: Input guide - Cursor mode](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/input_guide.html#cursor_mode)

> `glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED);`
>
> This will hide the cursor and lock it to the specified window. GLFW will then take care of all the details of **cursor re-centering** and offset calculation and providing the application with a virtual cursor position. This virtual position is provided normally via both the cursor position callback and through polling.

Each time you disable the cursor (that is on every middle-button press), the position of the cursor will be set to the center of the window.

So either don't disable the cursor, keep it disabled or deal with the re-centering.